# how do I access "correct" holidays in timeDate

Tags: r, date, calendar

Searched around but could not find the answer to this. Essentially, the timeDate package has some internal code it hasn't exposed, and I am wondering how to get at it:

```
> USDecorationMemorialDay(2013)

GMT
[1] [2013-05-30]

> holidayNYSE(2013)

NewYork
[1] [2013-01-01] [2013-01-21] [2013-02-18] [2013-03-29] [2013-05-27] [2013-07-04] [2013-09-02] [2013-11-28] [2013-12-25]
```

so as you can see here the USDecorationMemorialDay function is wrong as Memorial Day is the last monday of May. however in the holidayNYSE function they have somehow implemented a correction so it gives [2013-05-27]. What's up with that?

Bigger picture I'm really looking to have a national holiday calendar by country. timeDate has set up the UK, US, Switzerland, and Canada, but the rest of the G7 in particular Japan and Australia are missing. Perhaps this belongs in some other package? If it doesnt my plan is to basically do a mix of modify the existing timeDate functions and write those that dont exist. someone somewhere has probably already done this?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the function `holidayNYSE` function by typing the function name without parentheses in the console. You can see the relevant part here

```
if (y <= 1970) 
   holidays <- c(holidays, as.character(USDecorationMemorialDay(y)))
if (y >= 1971) 
   holidays <- c(holidays, as.character(USMemorialDay(y)))
```

Apparently USDecorationMemorialDay is a defunct holiday and only relevant for years prior to 1971.

For your bigger picture question, I'm not aware of any R package that does this. Perhaps you can scrape it from the web somewhere?

Comment: On June 28, 1968, the Congress passed the Uniform Monday Holiday Act, which moved four holidays, including Memorial Day, from their traditional dates to a specified Monday in order to create a convenient three-day weekend.